# What airlines offer complimentary alcohol from Ireland to the U.S.?

Tags: alcohol, delta-air-lines, british

I'm planning on travelling to California in August/autumn of this year after I receive my COVID vaccine. I know the flight will be long so I'm looking for an airline that offers free alcohol.

I've heard that all the U.S. airlines along with British airways.

Do they also offer unlimited free drinks or just one/two?

Comment: No airline offers "unlimited free drinks". Once they deem you not to be fit to receive more, they will stop serving you. Cue the arrogant people who end up in court after harassing crew who refused to serve them. Remember that alcohol and conditions in flight don't always mix very well. You probably also want to specify which class of travel you are thinking of. Many airlines will provide only basic service (e.g. a small bottle of wine with the meal) in coach while they will serve champagne and spirits in premium classes.

Comment: [Found with a simple search](https://www.tastingtable.com/travel/national/airlines-free-alcohol-beer-wine-spirits) although it's from 2017.

Comment: Also note that currently, vaccine or not, non-exempt non-US citizens coming or transit through Ireland or the UK (or the Schengen Area) are not allowed into the US. Hopefully this will change by then, but there's no guarantee it will. The ban has probably already lasted a lot longer than most people would have thought.

Answer (score 7):

That depends on the airline and very much on your class of service.

In economy class, most airlines will serve beer or wine with the first meal service. Most European airlines are a little more generous than the typical US carrier and might serve a pre-dinner drink as well (depending also on time of day).

In business and first, they will generally keep serving throughout the flight although they will often taper it down over time. Flight attendants will cut you off, if they feel you had enough and/or start to misbehave.

Keep in mind that the first thing you will in the US is to clear immigration and customs. Generally you want your wits about you during that process.

Comment: Those arriving from Ireland (Dublin and Shannon airports) will have precleared immigration; otherwise I agree wholeheartedly that it is important to be alert and responsive when flying to another country.

Comment: @RichardBeasley Those arriving from Ireland on a direct flight to the US. Given OP's mention of British Airways, I support routings via other countries are on the books.